# modify apk content

Tags: development, instant-apps

Do you know if it possible to edit compiled code in apk package?

I tried followed steps:

1. Unpack xapk file by command: `unzip my-app.xapk` (I have there multiple apk and I need to modify one of them, due to bug fixing...)
2. Unpack one of the apk: `apktool d my-component.apk`
3. Modify one of the smali files
4. Build apk: `apktool b ./my-component -o ./my-component.apk`
5. generate cert: `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias`
6. sign all unpacked from xapk files:
   `find ./ -name "*.apk" -exec apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.jks --ks-pass pass:123456 --out {} {} \;`
7. install all component: `adb install-multiple -r my-component.apk  another-component.apk....`

After all these steps my application works partially and I got some errors in logcat:

`ArtManagerService: Failed to prepare profile for my-package:/data/app/~~SeVk-WOasdas3A-hIPw==/my-component-TwgvYqasd_uL4r2tgdBZ-og==/base.apk`

Answer (score 0):

An .apk is a zip file, just a bit stricter.  Theoretically you could change anything in it.  But if the code is actually compiled, then it is an amazing amount of effort.

There is an article on [wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Edit-APK-Files) that tells you more about how to modify an apk file.